Can KinematicTrajectoryOptimization support gurobi solver
currently KinematicTrajectoryOptimization only support snopt or ifopt, is it possiable to support gurobi solver ?
when use gurobi solver, it throws a not support generic constraints exception
EXPECT_EQ(trajopt_.prog().linear_constraints().size(), 0);
VectorXd desired = VectorXd::Ones(num_positions_);
auto binding = trajopt_.AddPathVelocityConstraint(desired, desired, 0.5);
std::cout << "path velocity constraint:\t" << binding.to_string() << std::endl;
EXPECT_THAT(binding.to_string(), HasSubstr("path velocity constraint"));
EXPECT_EQ(trajopt_.prog().linear_constraints().size(), 1);
// r(0) = 0, r(1) = 1.
trajopt_.AddPathPositionConstraint(VectorXd::Zero(num_positions_), VectorXd::Zero(num_positions_), 0);
trajopt_.AddPathPositionConstraint(VectorXd::Ones(num_positions_),VectorXd::Ones(num_positions_), 1);
auto lb = VectorXd::Constant(3, -10);
auto ub = VectorXd::Constant(3, 10); 
trajopt_.AddAccelerationBounds(lb, ub);
trajopt_.AddDurationConstraint(1, 1);
trajopt_.AddDurationCost(50);
GurobiSolver solver;
solver.Solve(trajopt_.prog());


unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "GurobiSolver is unable to solve because a GenericConstraint was declared but is not supported." thrown in the test body.


Gurobi only supports convex optimization problems. The error you're seeing is reporting that the optimization you're generating with KinematicTrajectoryOptimization is not convex. (That's expected).
No, I'm afraid I wouldn't expect you to use Gurobi with KinematicTrajectoryOptimization.  GcsTrajectoryOptimization uses a very similar formulation, but goes to length to formulate the problem in a way that's suitable for convex solvers.

Hello Professor Russ, Thanks for your help.  I’m not sure which part is non-convex; the properties of B-splines are convex. I debug the generate constraints bellow
// acc jerk constraints
DerivativeConstraint described as 'acceleration bound 0, 0' with 4 decision variables duration(0) control_point(0,0) control_point(0,1) control_point(0,2) 

is this acc part no-convex ?

I was use KinematicTrajectoryOptimization  to robot trajectory optimization, is that ok change to GcsTrajectoryOptimization?

The time-scaling of the trajectories is perhaps the first thing that makes the kinematic trajectory optimization problem nonconvex. (of course collision avoidance tends to be a second one). To be convex, GcsTrajectoryOptimization using convex decompositions of the configuration space to handle the non-convexities of collision, and convex relaxations/reformulations to deal with the time-scaling, etc.
